# Images not loading on device but loading on Emulator

Tags: android, react-native

Good Evening...

I am working on react-native, developing an application & completely new in Android.
I have opened android project of react-native in android-studio and ran it on device.
But none of the images in the whole app are getting loading in the device, but they are getting loaded in Emulator.

In login screen Login Image got loaded

```
<ImageBackground
          source={require('../../assets/images/login_bg.png')}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >
```

In same login screen App logo hasn't loaded

```
<Image
              style={styles.logo}
              source={require('../../assets/images/app_logo.png')}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this warning in console of Android studio:
"The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.0."

I have updated the Android studio and the images have loaded into device.